# Get distinct results from wordpress / woocommerce search query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, distinct

I have been searching for weeks to work this out, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet ( mostly due to lack of knowledge ).

I have a WP website with woocommerce. Located here:

[www.importa-supplementen.nl](http://www.importa-supplementen.nl/winkel/) ( which is extremely slow, sorry )

I have upload many products. Because of our companies DB works, I have to upload product X 4 times if it has 4 different categories ( different SKU's ) etc. Nothing I can change there, unfortuantly. Now, when I want to search for product X on the front-end obviously I get 4 identical products ( trough the clients eyes ). For instance try searching for : "queen"

I have read they by 'add_filter' you can alter the search query in wordpress / woocommerce, but nothing seems to work for me. At least, the few I found. I need something that says:

SELECT distinct.....or maybe GROUP BY  ?

I read something about pre_get_posts ?

My website uses archive-product.php of woocommerce to display the search results.

I hope there is WP / woocommerce expert that can show me this. I think it should be very simple, but for me those solutions are many times the hardest to find. Thanks a bunch!

Bas

Comment: You can use `pre_get_posts` to exclude items of a certain taxonomy (in this case `product_cat`). But how would you know which categories to exclude? Ie: If product "Foo 1" is category A and "Foo 2" (a clone of "Foo 1") is in category B, which version of "Foo" should appear in the search results? Duplicating the product 4 times seems *very* backward. It completely defeats the point of WordPress taxonomies and your company should reconsider that if they actually want to use WooCommerce.

Comment: it's showing 4 items for a reason.. why would you want to exclude the other 3 items? and which should be hidden then? each has different SKU, so how would the other product reduced it's stock if you will not display it?

Comment: i do not work with stock. so that is no issue. but thanks for the heads up!

Comment: SKU is stock keeping unit...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to exclude terms from a front-end search query using `pre_get_posts`.

```
function so_34695883_exclude_product_category( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'actor',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'foo', 'bar' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ),
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so_34695883_exclude_product_category' );
```

Comment: `product_cat` is a custom taxonomy... you should use something like `$query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);`

Comment: You're probably right. Don't always test, will try to revise tomorrow.

Comment: thank you for all the effort ? I wrote this same website just custom made for another project and just use SELECT dinstict. Is this not possible ?

Comment: Edited with @Reigel's suggestion. I don't quite see how you'd select a distinct item as they will all have a unique. post_id`. If you can edit your post to share what you already have working then perhaps someone can help you adapt it to the WooCommerce/WordPress way.

Comment: And *maybe* the [`posts_where`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) is what you need? mySQL isn't my strong point.